# Same as vs same like

Tags: grammaticality

When I walk down the street now, no one looks at me with the same disdain **as** they used to.

When I walk down the street now, no one looks at me with the same disdain **like** they used to.

When I walk down the street now, no one looks at me with the same disdain they used to.

Are all these sentences grammatically correct? I am a little doubtful of the second sentence being grammatically correct, since most sources on the internet suggest that **same as** is what native speakers use in most contexts. "He's the same height as me.".

But the context here is different. And I've always been to consider the context, so here I am.

Answer (score 1):

If you are comparing two things, **same ... as** is the only grammatically correct option. So, your first sentence is correct and the other two are not. You could also say:

> When I walk down the street now, no one looks at me with the same disdain. - *implicit comparison*

> When I walk down the street now, no one looks at me with disdain. - *no comparison*

This sentence also works because it's equality rather than comparison.

> When I walk down the street now, no one looks at me with the disdain that they used to.

Comment: In your last example, is the usage of the word "that", preceding "they used to", mandatory for the sentence to be grammatically correct?

Comment: In informal speech, it's OK to omit **that** as a relative pronoun. You will also see it omitted in written English, but I prefer not to. I this case, I think that it helps a lot when parsing the sentence, because it is already subject ellipsis... "look at me with" in the that-clause has been ellipsized, so there's not a lot left of the that-clause.

Answer (score 0):

> ...no one looks at me with the same disdain as they used to.

The use of *as* in this sentence is correct.

---

> ...no one looks at me with the same disdain like they used to.

The use of *like* in this sentence is not correct, because *like* should apply to a noun, but is applied in this sentence to an action. However, this sentence is appropriate in vernacular speech, because native speakers are comfortable with the substitution of *like* for *as*, for many clauses.

---

> ...no one looks at me with the same disdain they used to.

Omitting *as* in this sentence is correct.  However, in this case, the sentence is a shortened form of the one in which *that* connects to the two clauses ("the same disdain *that* they used to"). Practically, the meaning is the same.